# Can we change include_once path using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a copy of a site on a live server and a local server. The files have so many include paths in it, which are like this:

```php
require_once "/long/path/on/server/to/the/site/functions.php";
```

Local server has this and other similar files located in the same directory

Now instead of changing all these paths on the files i am thinking of using .htaccess instead. This way I will keep the htaccess file on local only and wouldn't have to change paths all the time when uploading to live server.

So any ideas on this?

Comment: thank you @bo-persson and harper89 for fixing up my grammar :D

Comment: @jaspreet-chahal, never thought of it, thanks for letting me know. Just accepted one :)

Comment: @AamirSiddique just curious. What OS are we talking about??

Comment: @peehaa i am on Windows XP SP3. And using XAMPP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create symbolic links. That's makes it clean and easy. And can be easily integrated in your project.

For *nix you can use:

```
ln -s /path/to/original/ /path/to/linkName
```

For Windows (if the filesystem is NTFS) you can use:

```
mklink [/D] drive:/path/to/orignal drive:/path/to/linkName
```

Comment: thanks, i wish this was available in windows. My local host is windows but my server is linux.

Comment: thnx @peehaa 
I should've asnwered that with examples :(

Comment: Np @JaspreetChahal all for a better world :-)

Comment: thanks @PeeHaa and jaspreet-chahal. Windows links seems great but unfortunately i am on FAT32 :( Thanks anyway, i guess i have to go on with manual editing.

Answer (score 0):

You can define constant for path:

```
define('ROOT_PATH', '/long/path/on/server/to/the/site/');
require_once ROOT_PATH . "functions.php";
```

or you can change include paths

```
set_include_path('/long/path/on/server/to/the/site/');
require_once "functions.php";
```

Comment: thanks, i don't want to use this method because then i will have to edit so many files :(

Answer (score 0):

To make you life easier why don't you implement an autoloader:

```
class AutoLoader
{
    public function loadLibFile($class)
    {
        $filename = '/long/path/on/server/to/the/site/' . $class . '.php';

        if (!is_readable($filename)) {
            return false;
        }

        include($filename);
    }
}

$autoloader = new AutoLoader();

spl_autoload_register(array($autoloader, 'loadLibFile'));
```

Comment: thank you @peehaa, but in this method i would have to alter so many files, which i don't want to :(

Comment: That's ok. Then I would go the symlink route as answered by @jaspreet because you [can make symlinks in windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) (if the filesystem is NTFS). And if you are going to start a new project I would suggest making use of autoloading, because it just works great.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't even need to touch web-server configuration for this, as such a variable already defined in the properly configured server by default.

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/functions.php";
```

will load proper file in any environment.

Nevertheless, you can set whatever environment variable using `SetEnv` directive and read it from $_SERVER array in the PHP script.

However, you aren't supposed to use this variable all throughout your scripts.
Better practice would be to use it to create a constant which would be used later on.
You can mace creation of this constant conditional, depends on the environment.

For the systems with single entry point things become even more easier: you may have the root path built out of the entry point script address.

Comment: But what happens if their library files are outside the web root? Isn't it better to use the include_path ini directive for this?

Comment: I don't like include_path at all. I prefer to know where do my files take station exactly. For the paths outside of the webroot you can use relative addressing built from the document root.

Comment: But if you use relative addressing on the web document root you're still tying yourself down to your library files always being in the same place relative to your web root. At the very least setting an application-wide constant would be preferable in my eyes.

Comment: `your library files always being in the same place relative to your web root.` - YES! Exactly. I don't like my files to wander at random. That's the point.

Comment: Thanks guys, but in my case, i don't want to change any file for paths, i would have to alter so many files for that, which i don't want to. I was thinking if we can do it in htaccess, so whenever a file is included in a php document and called then somehow htaccess rewrite it. Is this possible?